# Which 12 month time frame is used for PCI merchant levels?

Tags: pci-dss

We self certified as a level 3 vendor in March of 2016. Since then we had far more transactions and may be in level 2 turf (ugh).

My question is, which 12 month period does the PCI certification look at to determine merchant level? The 12 months directly preceding the audit? (in which case if you are borderline do you just have to guess what level you are leading up to the audit?) Or is it the 12 months before the last audit?

Comment: As a minor nit, _more_ transactions would move you from level 2 to level 1, not to level 3.  Editing...  Aside from that, excellent question.

Comment: Just edited. I meant we certified as 3 and might be 2 now.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Mastercard US](https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/merchants/safety-security/security-recommendations/merchants-need-to-know.html), to determine your merchant level, you **look at the most recent 52-week period**:

> Determine merchant level using Mastercard transaction volume from the most recent 52-week period

So if you're having a PCI audit, your merchant level is determined from that moment in time.

That being said, each card brand has their own definition and requirements for each level. Many of them are similar. You can see a good breakdown [here](http://www.1stoppciscan.com/pci-scanning-faq/how-do-i-determine-my-pci-merchant-level/), but you should check with each card brand for the most up-to-date info.

The best solution is to contact your merchant services provider (credit card processor), and they should be able to tell you what level you fall in for each card brand, and what your PCI validation requirements are.